# express router (router.route(URL).get vs router.get(URL)

Tags: express, router

i`m quite confused between router.route.METHOD / router.METHOD

```
router.route('/login').get(function(req,res){
   console.log('hello world');
})

router.get('/login', function(req,res){
   console.log('hello world');
})
```

are the two sentences written above the same thing?

Comment: Read this article https://webapplog.com/url-parameters-and-routing-in-express-js/ read completely then only you will get an idea

Comment: Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Both means the same